# Como fazer uma cruz a partir de uma matriz no R

Tags: r, gráfico

Eu tenho a seguinte matriz:

```
      x y
A = | 2 0 |
    | 3 0 |
    | 1 2 |
    | 1 3 |
    | 2 1 |
    | 2 2 |
    | 2 3 |
    | 2 4 |
    | 3 2 |
```

Como faço posso fazer uma Cruz como na seguinte figura ao plotar essa matriz num gráfico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando usando a função plot() para gráfico de linhas

Answer (score 1):

Os dados não estão na ordem correta e estão incompletos, na pergunta só estão 9 linhas quando são necessárias 12, tantas quantos os pontos da figura. Incluo os dados corrigidos no fim.

Aqui vão duas maneiras de desenhar a cruz.
A primeira só com R base.

```
plot(0, type = "n", xlim = range(dados$x), ylim = range(dados$y))
segments(x0 = dados$x, y0 = dados$y,
         x1 = c(dados$x[-1], dados$x[1]), 
         y1 = c(dados$y[-1], dados$y[1]))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A segunda com o pacote `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = c(x[-1], x[1]), yend = c(y[-1], y[1]))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em ambas o truque é o mesmo, definir como pontos de fim de segmento os pontos `(x2, y2)`, `(x3, y3)`, etc, `(x1, y1)`.

**Dados.**

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
x y
2 0 
3 0 
3 2 
4 2
4 3 
3 3
3 4
2 4
2 3
1 3
1 2
2 2 
", header = TRUE)
```